# В чём преимущества плагина dropzone js перед обычным методом input?

Tags: reactjs

Я пытаюсь разобраться в методе загрузки файлов на сервер. Меня в том числе интересует php часть, где апи будет принимать запросы с файлами и давать ответ в формате json. Но вроде бы эту часть я кажется понял.

На пользовательской стороне будет react js приложение. И вот мне надо чтобы была область загрузки файла и кнопка отправки. Стандартная html форма отправки методом пост пеня не устраивает, так как мне нужно чтобы была ещё нагрузка с json ключами.

Я заметил в некоторых примерах используется dropzone js. Но мне интересно почему именно он? Почему нельзя допустим использовать `<input type="file">` где задать обработчик, который бы срабатывал после выбора файла и просто передавать выбранный файл вместе с json при помощи ajax?

Но почему-то в некоторых примерах используется для выбора файла именно dropzone. Это потому что там есть возможность перетаскивания файла? Или может он кодирует файл?

Объясните новичку. В передаче файлов мне ещё многое непонятно. Ну или может где-то есть хорошая статья где каждый элемент (выбор файла, его отправка вместе с json на сервер, php апи, которая принимает файл и даёт ответ на запрос) разбирается отдельно.

Comment: Для реакта есть отличный https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone . Он называется dropzone, потому что создаёт зону для дропа (дроп значит бросить). На указанной странице есть примеры использования

Comment: https://react-dropzone.js.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвечаю на ваши вопросы:

1. > Но мне интересно, почему именно он?

   Просто потому что это достаточно гибкая библиотека которая поддерживает 99% требований программистов.
2. > Почему нельзя, допустим, использовать `<input type="file">`, где задать обработчик, который бы срабатывал после выбора файла и просто передавать выбранный файл вместе с json при помощи ajax?

   Конечно можно, но зачем создавать велосипед, dropzone занимается именно тем же самым, если посмотреть в испектор браузера можно увидеть, что dropzone генерирует точно такой же `<input type="file">`.
3. > Это потому что там есть возможность перетаскивания файла?`

   Да и поэтому тоже.
4. > Или может он кодирует файл?

   Не совсем, dropzone оборачивает файлы в Blob объекты чтобы можно было их отображать в браузере в качестве preview. Если использовать [react-dropzone](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone) управление передается в ваше приложение через обратный вызов `onDrop`, вы получаете Blob объекты, которые вы уже можете кодировать как вам вздумается.

Статья по загрузке файла с клиента на API https://medium.com/technoetics/handling-file-upload-in-reactjs-b9b95068f6b

По php достаточно много есть туториалов и все зависит от того используете ли вы какой либо фреймворк, советую гуглить следующее `php <вставь имя фреймворка если есть> upload file tutorial`